# How to remove installed Jenkins from my local ?

Tags: jenkins, liferay, liferay-6

By mistake I installed jenkins in my workstation, basically I worked on a portal platform "Liferay" which use to start on Port"8080".

Afterward whenever I am trying to open localhost:8080 always jenkins page starts instead of Liferay home page.

What I did is:

```
sudo apt-get install jenkins.
```

System was running perfect but after restart it got this problem.
Please help me how to remove this jenkins from my pc.

I also tried this command `sudo apt-get remove jenkins`, but it still opening on same port.

Does it affect my workstation?

Comment: Uninstall jenkin using command : `sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove jenkins`

Comment: after removing jenkins you may have to restart the system